# cmd call to powershell "you must provide a value expression on the right hand side of the '-' operator"

Tags: variables, powershell, command, call

Before I go any further, my experience with Powershell amounts to only 2 days.

I am trying to call a powershell script from the command line with four parameters added to the command. The powershell script simply cleans a CSV file and makes a copy of the file at every stage of cleaning.

The variables `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` in the script relate to the new filenames (including the full address).

PowerShell Script

```
param(
  [string]$a,
  [string]$b,
  [string]$c,
  [string]$d


 )



Get-Content $a | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace """""""""""","""""" } | Set-Content $b -Force
Get-Content $b | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace """""""","""" } | Set-Content $c -Force
Get-Content $c | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace """""","" } | Set-Content $d -Force
```

**Command Script**

The command script below is what I am trying to run in `cmd` (note: I have taken out the real addresses).

```
powershell.exe '\\somefileaddress\CleanData.ps1' 
-a "\\someaddress\DrFA-C.csv" 
-b "\\someaddress\DrFA-C_2.csv" 
-c "\\someaddress\DrFA-C_3.csv"
-d "\\someaddress\DrFA-C_4.csv"
```

The error message i am getting is:

> You must provide a value expression on the right hand side of the '-' operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that the problem isn't with your script but with how you're calling it.  This works for me (without the newlines which were inserted for clarity):

```
powershell.exe -Command "& '\\somefileaddress\CleanData.ps1' 
-a '\\someaddress\DrFA-C.csv' 
-b '\\someaddress\DrFA-C_2.csv' 
-c '\\someaddress\DrFA-C_3.csv' 
-d '\\someaddress\DrFA-C_4.csv'"
```

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't sound like this answer addresses this question specifically, but just in case it helps someone some day:

I had this error message when running a script which was written for PowerShell v5 on a Windows 7 computer with PowerShell v2 installed (the default version for Windows 7). It was a really complex line and the way it was written just didn't play well with older versions of PowerShell.

Run this code in PowerShell: `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major` and if it returns `2` (or maybe even `3`?) you can try upgrading your version of PowerShell by installing [this Windows update.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50395)

Answer (score 1):

You're using double quotes, which makes it an expandable string (the parser is going to look for Powershell operators in the string, and try to invoke those operators during the parsing).  The - is a Powershell operator, so it thinks you're tring to do some sort of subtraction operation.

Switch to single quotes to tell it that you want that string interpreted literally.